# Requesting MS Graph Access Token registered in Azure Active Directory C#

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am new to MS Graph . I created in the App Registration portal and was trying to retrieve access token from Azure Active Directory programmatically. Kindly review the code and could you please let me know the reason for the access token to be null.

[App Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8arLm.png)

```html
ClientCredentialProvider clientCredential = new ClientCredentialProvider()
{
                authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx",
                client_id = "xxxx",
                client_secret = "xxxx",
                resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
 };
var credential = new ClientCredential(clientCredential.client_id, clientCredential.client_secret);
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(clientCredential.authority);
var token = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(clientCredential.resource, credential);
Console.WriteLine("Token:", token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the AcquireTokenAsync is an async method, it will always wait for complete. Use the code as below to get access token:

```
var token = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential).Result.AccessToken;
```